# Change Font Style

Tags: c#

I have a label with text in **Bold** and *Italic* . I want to change those font properties through a button click.

I got to know of the code `Label1.Font = new Font(Label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);`

But from this code it will undo both **BOLD** & *ITALIC* properties. I want only to remove **bold** property.....

Are there anything like `fontsyle.bold = false` ?

Comment: Extra text like multiple exclamation points and "thank you notes" are not necessary. Discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [Font.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.style.aspx) of original font when creating new one, use `& ~` to flip styles

```
   label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this also --

```
label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
```

or

```
mainForm.lblName.Font = new Font("Arial", mainForm.lblName.Font.Size);
```

The constructor takes different parameters. [see more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to use bitcodes and the XOR operator ^

try this code:

```
Label1.Font = new Font(Label1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me...this one did! Learned something new from someone with only a 1 rep. :-) I suppose there was a time when Mr. Skeet only had 1 rep also...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btn_bold_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = label2.Font = new Font( label1.Font,label1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
    }

    private void btn_italic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = label2.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Italic);
    }

    private void btn_underline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = label2.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline);
    }
```

This will do all what do u want

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this will do what he need ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had four checkboxes, one for each of Bold, Italic, Underline, and Strikeout. You could use a method like this to get a font style based on what you want:

```
    private FontStyle GetFontStyle(bool bBold, bool bItalic, bool bUnderline, bool bStrikeout)
    {
        FontStyle FS = new FontStyle();
        if (bBold) FS = FS ^ FontStyle.Bold;
        if (bItalic) FS = FS ^ FontStyle.Italic;
        if (bUnderline) FS = FS ^ FontStyle.Underline;
        if (bStrikeout) FS = FS ^ FontStyle.Strikeout;
        return FS;
    }
```

And then you could use it to set your label's font like this, using the checkbox values:

```
Label1.Font = new Font(Label1.Font,
    GetFontStyle(
        chkBold.Checked,
        chkItalic.Checked,
        chkUnderline.Checked,
        chkStrikeout.Checked)
    );
```